# how to open pdf file in firefox browsers window

Tags: jquery, firefox

I want to open any pdf file links to new browser window. The following jquery code works fine except in firefox which opens file save dialog.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

can we possibly force firefox to open the document like chrome?

Comment: If it opens file save, then acrobat reader is not installed correctly or the mime type from the server is not application/pdf

Comment: Does your Firefox open or save the PDF when you don't specify the target?  This has nothing to do with whether or not you apply a target to all of your anchors, and everything to do with what the browser is configured to do with that response type.  And it can change from browser to browser, you can't control it for other users.

Answer (score 1):

David is right. The browser behavior for opening certain MIME types, like PDF varies according to browsers, browser versions, operating systems, etc. You can even force the download of the resource, instead of visualizing it. In conclusion, that's something out of our control.

Comment: i agree with David too as this seems like browser configuration issue but then I m able to open and view this document in firefox without downloading http://static.mozilla.com/moco/en-US/pdf/mozilla_privacypolicy.pdf and the document available on my link is always coming with Save dialog.

Comment: Could it be then something to do with the mime type not correctly set for the pdf file links? If so can I possibly set the mime type using Jquery as  $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('content-Type','application/pdf');

Comment: The content type is configured in your Web Server (Apache, IIS, nginx, etc). If you're always getting a save dialog, check through your web server configuration.